# jQuery to add a class to all last childs in a nested list

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-selectors, nested, css-selectors

I have a list structured like this:

```
<ul class="tree" id="tree">
    <li>1</li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="?character=?">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="?character=?">3</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="?character=?">4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="?character=?">5</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="?character=?">6</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="?character=?">7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="?character=?">8</a></li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

What I need to do is use jQuery to select all the `last:childs` in the list (i.e., 1,5,6,8) and give the all `class="last"`.

For some reason the using CSS `ul:last child` doesn't work at all, and I've tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("ul li:last-child").addClass("last");
   });
  </script>
```

which didn't work. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1, 5, 6 and 8 have been selected

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("ul > li:last-of-type").addClass("last");
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/42v8A/

Answer (score 0):

have you tried ??

```
$('ul > li:last-child').addClass("last");
```

or you can do

```
$('ul li').last().addClass("last");
```

Comment: I'm wondering if `$('li').last()` will not just select the last `li` in whole of them in the DOM...

Comment: This doesn't select either 1 or 6.

Comment: @JoDev edited :) again typo.Thanks you very much.you saved me.

Comment: @hjpotter92 that is a typo.JoDev informed me already.Edited my answer.

Comment: @Baadshah It won't work even then. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/FfksS/) and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/FfksS/1/)

Comment: @JoDev ,hjpotter yes.Came to know about "last-of-type" now :).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `>` :

```
$('ul > li:last-child').addClass('last');
```

Or you can use the [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) jQuery method like this :

```
$('ul li').last().addClass('last');
```

Like @ashley answer, see [last-of-type](http://api.jquery.com/last-of-type-selector/), this will works :

```
$('ul > li:last-of-type').addClass('last');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul > li:last-child').addClass("last");
```

You need to consider child elements of ul

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong `<ul>` `<li>` structure. This is the correct structure

```
         <ul class="tree" id="tree">
           <li>1</li>
             <li>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="?character=?">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="?character=?">3</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <ul>
                           <li><a href="?character=?">4</a></li>
                           <li><a href="?character=?">5</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="?character=?">6</a></li>
                    <li>
                       <ul>
                         <li><a href="?character=?">7</a></li>
                         <li><a href="?character=?">8</a></li>
                       </ul>
                    </li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
        </ul>
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/5QBYW/2/

Answer (score 0):

change your HTML to

```
<ul class="tree" id="tree">
<li>1</li>
<li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="?character=?">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="?character=?">3</a></li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="?character=?">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="?character=?">5</a></li>
             </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="?character=?">6</a></li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="?character=?">7</a></li>
                <li><a href="?character=?">8</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$("ul").each(function(){
$(this).find('li:last-child').addClass("last");
});
```

But here the desired result (selecting 1,5,6,8) wont happen. It selects only last list item in every unordered list

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is a bit odd. You are closing your `li` and creating a new list entirely. That isn't how nested lists function. The markup should be like:

### HTML

```
<ul class="tree" id="tree">
    <li>1
        <ul>
            <li><a href="?character=?">2</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="?character=?">3</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="?character=?">4</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="?character=?">5</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="?character=?">6</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="?character=?">7</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="?character=?">8</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and then, your normal CSS's `ul > li:last-child` will function.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.
Try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tree li:not(:has(li)").last().addClass("last");
   });
  </script>
```